# Package name in React Native Project (RN CLI). I have to use package name in firebase

Tags: android, reactjs, react-navigation, android-manifest, package-name

In location: android/app/src/androidmanifest.xml we usually and according to [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/#generating-android-credentials) find package name of our project. But i can't find it there. How can i get my app package name?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I also opened androidmanifest.xml file in android studio but still i can't find my project package name. Don't know where to find now. Some Youtube tutorials say some lines of code line in this file are hidden when can be seen in android studio but still no solution.